# Java: increase page load time script

Tags: java, php, onload

I want to know is there a way (by java or php) to increase page load time `onload` to simulate overload of the server.

I have tried `delayer()` "function" but this actualy loads the page.

Comment: in php you can use sleep() that'll basically lock the page  from processing any further until its timed out.

Comment: Thank both of you :) I prefer sleep() from PHP because someone may have java turned off. Hovever I can not mark @Dave answer so I did mark user1145753. Anyway both are good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Thread.sleep(long milliseconds) in your servlet code.
From the Thread class javadoc:

> Causes the currently executing thread to sleep (temporarily cease execution) for the specified number of milliseconds, subject to the precision and accuracy of system timers and schedulers.